# Sequelize join twice on two tables

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two table: `Conversations` and `ConversationParticipants`.
I need to get the list of conversations that both users `1` and `2` participate too.
In `MySQL`, the query would be this:

```
SELECT conversation_participants.conversation_id FROM conversation_participants
JOIN conversations t1
    ON t1.conversation_id = conversation_participants.conversation_id
    AND conversation_participants.user_id = 11
JOIN conversation_participants t2
    ON t1.conversation_id = t2.conversation_id
    AND t2.user_id = 2
```

However, in Sequelize I cannot understand how to set models relations so that I can make a single query. I tried this without success (please note that this is almost pseudo code, reported as such for clarity):

```
var Conversation = sequelize.define('conversations', {
    conversationId:  Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
});

var ConversationParticipant = sequelize.define('conversation_participants', {
    participationId:  Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    userId:  Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    conversationId : Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,        
});
Conversation.hasMany(ConversationParticipant, { as : 'Participants'});
```

and then

```
ConversationParticipant.findAll({
    where : { userId : 1 },
    include : [{
        model : Conversation,
        as : 'conversation',
        include : [{
            model : ConversationParticipant,
            as : 'Participants',
            where : { userId : 2 }
        }]
}]
```

I get the following error:
`Error: conversation_participants is not associated with conversations!`.
Any idea?

Comment: `Conversation.hasMany(Participant, { as : 'Participants'});` what is `Participant`? Where is it defined?

Comment: yes sorry, typo. will edit now.

Comment: dont you have a definition from `ConversationParticipant` to `Conversation`, like `belongsTo`?

Comment: @demarchisd I tried but then I would get an error ("cannot create foreign key") from sync()

Comment: Your question introduced me to this awesome library and I was desperate in need of this library...

Comment: The tables are created by sequelize, or you're referencing already created tables? The [belongsTo] function (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongsto) has an option to specify the foreign key, maybe you could try that

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is find the conversations that have participants with user 1 or 2, and afterwards filter the conversations that have both of them:

```
const userIdsFilter = [1,2];

//find Conversations that have user 1 OR user 2 as participants,
Conversation.findAll({
    include : [{
        model : ConversationParticipant,
        as : 'conversation_participants',
        where : { userId : { $in: userIdsFilter }}
    }]
}).then((conversations) => 
{
    //filter the conversations that have the same length participants
    //as the userIdsFilter length (that way it excludes the ones
    //that have just one of the users as participants)
    return conversations.filter((conversation) => 
        conversation.conversation_participants.length === userIdsFilter.length);
}).then((conversations) => 
{
    //do what you need with conversations..
})
```

Comment: yes programmatically it's clearly an option, but I would like to do this in the query itself...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the belongsTo association in the `ConversationParticipant` definition. Sequelize model needs explicit association since you are trying to access `Conversation` via the `ConversationParticipant` instance even though `Conversation` is associated `ConversationParticipant` is not.

Something like this in addition to hasMany association:

```
ConversationParticipant.belongsTo(Conversation, { as : 'conversation',
  foreignKey: 'conversationId', targetKey: 'conversationId'});
```

And then remove the `conversationId` field definition from `ConversationParticipant` model since `belongsTo` also creates that for you.

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately as I said in a previous comment if I do this:

     Conversation.hasMany(ConversationParticipant, { as : 'Participants'});
 ConversationParticipant.belongsTo(Conversation, { as : 'conversation' , foreignKey: 'conversation_id', target: 'conversation_id'});
 Conversation.sync({force:true});
 ConversationParticipant.sync({force:true});

I get the following error when invoking the `findAll` method as described in the question: `Error: conversation_participants is not associated to conversations!

Comment: Just fixed the typo in `targetKey` in my answer. Don't underscore the properties by yourself, leave that to Sequelize. This should work. Also don't forget to take out the `conversationId` field from the `ConversationParticipant` model. See if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I get the following error if I change to `targetKey`: `/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/belongs-to.js:64 _ TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined`

Comment: Okay that's a different error and I think it's because now your model is different than the database state. You need to sync, you have a foreign key in `CoversationParticipant` instead of regular integer field. The code is syntactically correct and is working -> http://pastebin.com/AreHrVEU